# How to prove that this sequence converges to zero?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a natural number $k$ and a real number $a$ such that $|a|<1$, defines a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by

$$x_n = \frac{a^nn!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$

Show that $x_n\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I noticed that you still haven't accepted an answer.  Was there something about the question that is still unclear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note the following:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right|
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a^{n+1}(n+1)!}{k!(n+1-k)!} \cdot\frac{k!(n-k)!}{a^nn!}\right|\\
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a(n+1)}{n+1-k}\right|\\
=|a|<1
$$
What does that tell you about the sequence?

Comment: +1 Nice work. But as a further hint (unless there's a more direct one I'm missing) I'd ask "What does that tell you about the infinite series $\,\sum x_n\;$  and then what does this tell you about $\;\{x_n\}\;$ "?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I suppose that's a good point to address. OP: The above is certainly a valid line of reasoning if you can use the ratio test.  If not, you have to show that for sufficiently large $n$, $|x_n|$ is bounded above by a $k^n$ by some constant $k$ such that $0<k<1$. From there, the squeeze theorem finishes the job.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Also, thanks!

Comment: I don't get your point, @Omnomnomnom : how what you showed proves that $\,|x_n|<k^n\;$ for some $\,0<k<1\;$ ? With a little twist it can be proved $\,\{x_n\}\,$ is monotone descending, but for that...

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, I should say $|x_n|<b\,k^n$, for some constant $b$ (with enough messing around the $b$ isn't necessary, but it's easier and close enough). Anyway, by the definition of a limit, we say that $\exists N\in\mathbb Z$ such that $|x_n/x_{n+1}|<k=(1+a)/2$ for all $n>N$. That is, $|x_{n+1}|<k|x_n|$ for all such $n$. By induction, this becomes $x_n<k^{n-N}|x_N|$ for all such $n$. This, by the way, is how you would go about proving the ratio test.

Comment: By the ratio test for sequence we conclude that the sequence goes to zero. Is it correct?

Comment: So the ratio test actually tells us a little bit more, i.e., that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges.  But yes; that is certainly enough to show that $x_n\to0$